# how to "store" a specific keyboard shortcut on mac touch bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

it is possible to configure the touch bar to launch `cmd + ctrl + shift + 3` from the touch bar via the "Customize Control Strip..." setting.

I would also like to store the keyboard shortcut `cmd + ctrl + shift + 4` in the touch bar, so I can launch it from there.

so far I was unable to find a way to do so. any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can assign custom shortcuts to the Touch Bar.

For this you need a separate application called [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) (BTT).

With BTT installed

1. open the app
2. Click "TouchBar" to assign a TouchBar setting
3. Click "TouchBar Button"
4. Enter a Name below "Touch Bar Button Name"
5. Click below "Custom Keyboard Shortcut"
6. Press your desired key sequence